# Changing text color with drop-down box and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to make a web page where there is a drop-down box that has a list of colors. Choosing one of the colors will make the sentences(the p's under the code for the drop-down list) change to that color. Everything is fine except that when I choose the color in the drop-down list, the text color does not change.

### HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="colorchange.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <select>
                <!--This is the drop-down list-->
                <option id="red" onclick="changeColor()">Red</option>
                <option id="orange" onclick="changeColor()">Orange</option>
                <option id="yellow" onclick="changeColor()">Yellow</option>
                <option id="green" onclick="changeColor()">Green</option>
                <option id="blue" onclick="changeColor()">Blue</option>
                <option id="purple" onclick="changeColor()">Purple</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <!--These are the sentences that have to change text color-->
        <p>Sentence 1</p>
        <p>Sentence 2</p>
        <p>Sentence 3</p>
        <p>Sentence 4</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

### JavaScript - colorchange.js

```
function changeColor() {
    document.getElementById("red")
    document.p.style.color = red;

    document.getElementById("orange")
    document.p.style.color = orange;

    document.getElementById("yellow")
    document.p.style.color = yellow;

    document.getElementById("green")
    document.p.style.color = green;

    document.getElementById("blue")
    document.p.style.color = blue;

    document.getElementById("purple")
    document.p.style.color = purple;
}
```

Can someone help me with the code?

Comment: Sure, just remove all the onclick stuff and use onchange on the select element instead.

Comment: it should be pretty obvious that your function changes everything regardless of color selected. Also use browser console to check errors, you have unquoted colors which would make them undefined variables that would throw errors

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code.

1. All if your options call `changeColor()`, which means that clicking *any* option will execute *all* that code. So you need to find some way of separating or specifying the individual color you want.
2. `document.getElementById('red')` references the element with the `id` of `red`. This line by itself doesn't *do* anything other than referencing, so you normally need to add to it to do anything. Something like `document.getElementById('red').style.color = 'red'`. But since the element with the `id` of `red` is an `<option>` inside the dropdown menu, this is not what you want. You want to reference the `<p>` elements instead, and change their color.
3. `document.p` does not reference the `<p>` elements. `document.p` references the `p` property of the object `document`. This property doesn't exist. In JavaScript, you usually want to use one of these: `document.getElementById('id')`, `document.getElementsByTagName('tag')`, or `document.getElementsByClassName('class')`. Note that with tag name and class name, the `Elements` is plural, since you're referencing a list of *all* the elements with that tag or class. So you usually need to narrow things down a bit, or use a loop to execute some code for each item in the list.
4. This one's not so much a problem, but rather a better way of doing what you're trying to do. Instead of setting `id`s for the `<option>`s, just set their `value`s and then in JavaScript, you can just reference the `value` of the `<select>` element. A dropdown menu's `<select>` element will have the value of whichever `<option>` the user has chosen.

Having said all that, here is how I would write the code to do what you want.

HTML:

```
<select id="colorChanger">
    <option>Choose a color</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="purple">Purple</option>
</select>

<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<p>Paragraph 3</p>
<p>Paragraph 4</p>
```

JS:

```
//add an event listener that calls changeColor() when the menu selection changes
//this is the same as adding onchange="changeColor()" in HTML
document.getElementById('colorChanger').addEventListener('change', changeColor);

function changeColor() {
    //store the menu's value (which is the value of the chosen option)
    var color = document.getElementById('colorChanger').value;

    //store the list of all <p> elements
    var list = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

    //loop through the list and apply the color to each <p> element        
    for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
        list[i].style.color = color;
    }
}
```

or JS with jQuery:

```
//add an event listener that calls changeColor() when the menu selection changes
//this is the same as adding onchange="changeColor()" in HTML
$('#colorChanger').on('change', changeColor);

function changeColor() {
    //store the menu's value (which is the value of the chosen option)
    var color = $('#colorChanger').val();

    //apply the color to all <p> elements
    //(this is one of the benefits of using jQuery, it's much easier to apply certain changes)
    $('p').css('color', color);
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flowstoneknight/ryt7tr16/) with the JS.

And here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flowstoneknight/9nkxL17q/) with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should do it - jQuery and vanilla JS solutions provided. It's also worth noting that this will change the colour of **every** `p` tag on the page.

```
<select id="change-color">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
    <!-- more options as required -->
</select>
```

---

```
// jQuery
// whenever [id=change-color] changes its value
$('#change-color').on('change', function() {
    // set every <p> tag to be the colour of the selected options value attribute
    $('p').css('color', $select.val());
});

// JS
document.getElementById('change-color').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('p').style.color = this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value;
}
```

If you don't want to match every `p` tag, and only some of them, you can do this:

```
<p class="change-color">Something</p>
<p>Unchanged</p>
```

---

```
// jQuery
$('#change-color').on('change', function() {
    // Same as before, except only match <p> with 'change-color' class
    $('p.change-color').css('color', $select.val());
});

// JS
document.getElementById('change-color').onchange = function() {
    // Get every <p> tag in the document
    var ps = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
    // Iterate over them
    for (var i in ps) {
        // If their 'class' attribute contains the change-color class...
        if ( -1 !== (' '+ps[i].className+' ').indexOf(' change-color ') ) {
            // Change the colour of just this <p> tag and continue looping
            ps[i].style.color = this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value;
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, if you use the final example (vanilla JS, match-by-class) and want to be able to stamp anything with the "change-color" class, you can just do `document.getElementsByTagName('*')` to get every element on the page, instead of just the `<p>` tags. Obviously, this will be **relatively** resource intensive if you have a large number of elements in the page.